# How to automate release and staging phases with token using Jenkins and Artifactory?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jenkins-api

I want to automate the Artifactory release and staging in jenkins job.

I got this curl command,

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9090/job/artifactory-8.0-release/artifactory/staging?
```

it is working fine, but it is asking for authentication. When i do automate, i need to call this only using token not with user credentials.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to use tokens for authentication.

**Basic Authentication**

```
curl -u<USERNAME>:<TOKEN> http://ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/system/ping
```

**Authorization Headers**

```
curl -H"Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" http://ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/system/ping
```

Source: JFrog Artifactory documenation page '[Access Tokens](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens)'